Sound and Mic not working on my ubuntu 20.4 dell xps laptop
Sound and Mic stopped (inbuilt) working on my dell xps laptop. Ouput show dummy option and input shows nothing. Please help i have been trying to solve it for days.
Here are details:
System Information
        Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
        Product Name: XPS 9315
        Version: Not Specified
        Serial Number: 3RDNRV3
        UUID: 4c4c4544-0052-4410-804e-b3c04f525633
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: 0B14
        Family: XPS
    
uname -r
5.15.0-125-generic

sudo lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4602 (rev 06)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 46aa (rev 0c)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 461d (rev 06)
0000:00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 465d (rev 06)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 466e (rev 06)
0000:00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 463f (rev 06)
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 464f (rev 06)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 461e (rev 06)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 463e (rev 06)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 51fc (rev 01)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ed (rev 01)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 51ef (rev 01)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f0 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51e8 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51e9 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51e0 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 51e3 (rev 01)
0000:00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51a8 (rev 01)
0000:00:1e.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51aa (rev 01)
0000:00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51ab (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5187 (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51cc (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 51a3 (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 51a4 (rev 01)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 464d (rev 06)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation Device 5019 (rev 01)

sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: vikas-XPS Kernel: 5.15.0-125-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 9315 v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 00KRKP v: A00 serial: <superuser/root required> 
  UEFI: Dell v: 1.24.0 date: 09/11/2024 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: intel-ipu6 
  Device-2: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-125-generic

